# How to calculate addition and subtraction in sas

Tags: sas

How to calculate this below

Used below formula in Microsoft excel

```
   C = col1-col2- col3 + col4
```

I used below logic to convert above formula into SAS

```
   C1 = col1-col2
   C2 = sum(col3,col4)
   C1= C1-C2
```

Still not able to match value with Microsoft excel output

Comment: You can use the exact same syntax in SAS.

Comment: your SAS steps become the formula `c = col1 - col2 - col3 - col4`, which is different than the Excel formula, so it's a good thing the results don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap it in a datastep:

```
data new_data;
   set old_data;
   C = col1 - col2 - col3 + col4;
run;
```